# Zend Doctrine Session SaveHandler. How make it work?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, zend-session

I am trying to understand how to set up a Session Save Handler (with Zend/Doctrine) using a database table but I am a bit confused about how it all should work.

I found [this](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Doctrine+-+Matthew+Lurz) proposal that I think it suits my needs as I am also working with Doctrine.

All is set up: the proper class, the database table and Doctrine Model. What I don't get is this part:

```
$config = array(
'tableName'         => 'Session',
'dataColumn'        => 'data',
'lifetimeColumn'    => 'lifetime',
'modifiedColumn'    => 'modified',
'primaryKeyColumn'  => 'id',
);

Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Doctrine($config));
Zend_Session::start();
```

I am confused here. Where should this part go? Can anyone please help? Or maybe point me to some useful tutorial to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should go in your main bootstrap class (`application/Bootstrap.php`). So I'd add something like this:

```
protected function _initDoctrineSession()
{
    $config = array(
        'tableName'         => 'Session',
        'dataColumn'        => 'data',
        'lifetimeColumn'    => 'lifetime',
        'modifiedColumn'    => 'modified',
        'primaryKeyColumn'  => 'id',
    );

    Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Doctrine($config));
    Zend_Session::start();
}
```